# parallel invocation of kernel in OpenCl?

Tags: opencl

Does the following code, invokes all the 4 kernel in parallel and all the 4 events will wait for them to complete?

```
    event1 = event2 = event3 = event4 = 0;
    printf("sending enqueue task..\n");
    clEnqueueTask(command_queue, calculate1, 0, NULL, &event1);
    clEnqueueTask(command_queue, calculate2, 0, NULL, &event2);
    clEnqueueTask(command_queue, calculate3, 0, NULL, &event3);
    clEnqueueTask(command_queue, calculate4, 0, NULL, &event4);
    printf("waiting after enquing task..\n");
    clWaitForEvents(1, &event1);
    clWaitForEvents(1, &event2);
    clWaitForEvents(1, &event3);
    clWaitForEvents(1, &event4);
```

Or, is it the right way to perform the task for invoking all the kernels parallel? Is it even possible? What device info i need to see for confirming the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These tasks *might* execute in parallel, if you are using an out-of-order command queue and the device has support for executing multiple kernels in parallel. Unfortunately, there isn't any device info query that you can perform to verify whether the device has this capability, so you'll have to check the start/end times of the resulting events if you want to check whether this actually happened. An alternative method of achieving parallel kernel execution is by using multiple command queues (as discussed in the comments). Note that this kind of coarse-grained task parallelism won't execute particularly efficiently on massively parallel architectures such as GPU.

Rather than waiting for each event individually, you could just call `clFinish(command_queue)` to wait for all commands to complete. You might also want to experiment with calling `clFlush(command_queue)` immediately after enqueuing all the tasks to ensure that they are all submitted to the device.

Comment: hi @jprice. thanks again for your reply. i cross checked the behavior.. i bench-marked the code for clEnqueueTask and clFinish.. clEnqueueTask is happening faster and clFinish time is taking more which displays, enqueueing task is happening quickly and host is waiting for clFinish to complete. but, what all tasks i am adding in queue is not happening parallel because increasing the number of tasks/kernels in the queue increases the whole execution time. that means command_queue is solving them in a queue. Please suggest, my understanding is correct or not?

Comment: and i suppose this should be obvious.. command queue is not meant to solve them in parallel. this is a queue.. right?

Comment: The `clEnqueueTask` call is asynchronous and should return almost immediately, which is why all your time is spent waiting for `clFinish`. If you created your queue with the `CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE ` flag, then it is *allowed* to overlap the execution of your commands. It doesn't necessarily mean it will, but if the hardware allows it, it *might*.

Comment: It practice, that never happen to me with any OpenCL hardware. But is there any need for it? The hardware is 100% usage with that queue, why should you bother resplitting the job in parallel blocks that run at the same time but that 4times longer to complete?

Comment: @DarkZeros I never thought in this dimension.. solving 1 command queue will have 100% usage? that means if i am sending 4 commands in a queue, am i asking processor for 400% of load? please provide me some guidance regarding allocating commands to command queues.. and one more benchmark i did.. if i try to form 4 different command queue, each for separate command.. my program speed in increasing as per the number of command queue..

Comment: @Vishwadeep Yes, using multiple command queues is another away of trying to get commands to execute in parallel, if using an out-of-order queue doesn't work.

Comment: or you mean to say that it will not make it parallel.. it will serialize it.. and will fail the whole purpose of opencl

Comment: @Vishwadeep 1 queue can saturate the HW by loading it to 100% of usage. However, in practice using more command queues is recommended, since copy (IO) commands can run in parallel to other commands. However, even if you use 100 queues, the HW is just 1, and can only attend 1 kernel at a time. If you split it somehow in order to use half the resources for a kernel and half for another, it would take twice to finish, so you would be in the same situation. No speed increase from it, so better use 1 queue for kernel and 1 queue for IO. Thats all.

Comment: @DarkZeros The OP is asking about task parallelism with `clEnqueueTask`, which only launches a single work-item and definitely won't saturate the device. This is why they are looking to execute multiple kernels (tasks) in parallel, which CPUs and many recent GPUs support.

Comment: @jprice Oh, my bad I didn't remember EnqueueTask uses 1 WI only. Then it is a problem indeed, but it cannot be done with the current drivers (nVIDIA/AMD) as far as I know. Even in out of order queue modes, or multiple queues the HW only launches a kernel at a time. The only solutions would is to split the device in sub-devices. BU I personally have never tried that.

Comment: @DarkZeros Actually I've done this with multiple queues on AMD hardware and it works just fine. I'm pretty sure it should work on the latest NVIDIA hardware as well - this is essentially what they call 'Hyper-Q' (though it's possible this doesn't work with OpenCL of course).